# Backref in SQLAlchemy with subquery

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using subquery to perform filters (select object whose  attribute  has value less than 40). 
For these objects I want to use backref to access the objects referenced by relationships. 
This doesn't work. Here is the code outline.

```
class home(Base):
        __tablename__='home_table'
        hid = Column(..)

class person(Base):
    href = relationship("home", backref('hometable', order_by=hid)

#### this works ###############
for p in session.query(persons).all():
     print p.home # this works

###### this doesn't work ########
stmt = session.query(persons).filter(<some filter>).subquery()
for p in session.query(stmt).all():
    print p.home  ### fails, error: 'NamedTuple' object has no attribute 'house_hold'
```

How can I fix this. Should I use something other than subquery. The objective is to create subsets and then walk through their relationships.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `subquery()`?

Comment: I don't have to stick with subquery certainly. the stmt (result of subquery) comes from a function. I do further processing on it (filters and projections) before actually reading the values. If there is another way to handle the same I would do so. Essentially, I want to specify the filters piecewise.